# Why does "\s|\t|(\r ?\n)" catch single white space " ", but "(\r ?\n)|\s |\t" does not?

Tags: c#, regex

Why does `\s|\t|(\r ?\n)` catch single white space  , but `(\r ?\n)|\s |\t` does not?

I was testing my GUI text input for any white space, tab or new lines and noticed this.

I was testing on https://regexr.com/ if it makes a difference.

Comment: Is there supposed to be white space in the second regex? I copied the title. TBF it'd help if you put the actual regexs into the question itself

Comment: We note that the second regular expression has a space character following `\s`. So that would match a whitespace character followed by a space.

Comment: Look into `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`. Your second regex will work the way you expect (with respect to the `"\s "` part) using this option.

Comment: @Liam I was in the middle of editing when you already did it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\s` matches whitespace characters. In your first example, you have a pattern that is just `|\s|`*, but in the second you have `|\s |`* (with a space AFTER the whitespace). So the second pattern requires TWO whitespace to match.

*I added the vertical bars to help show the extra whitespace. SO dropped the space without something following it

Answer (score -3):

AH spacing matters. Characters are a valid token.

`(\r?\n)|\s|\t` =/= `(\r ?\n)|\s |\t`

Comment: This needs more explanation

Comment: Yes, a space character is a significant token in a regular expression.